# Google Sheets Iterative Calculation Possible Race Condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use iterative calculations to vary a cell's value to achieve the minimum value in another cell. So I have one "variable" cell, several intermediate cells that perform calculations, and then an "objective" cell. I want to find the value of the variable cell that minimizes (or approximately minimizes) the objective cell.

The way I have tried to accomplish this is by creating 2 copies of the data in adjacent columns, and setting the variable cell in the new columns to be an increment up and an increment down from the original column. The original variable cell then finds which column contains the minimum of the three objective cells, and is set to the variable cell of that column. So if the column where the variable cell has been incremented up has a better objective cell, the original variable cell is incremented up. In theory, it would continue to do so until hitting a minimum or reaching the maximum number of iterations I have set. I tested this method with some simple calculations, finding the min of a quadratic function, and it works (though I am sure there is a more optimized way to do it using apps script).

The problem is that when I implement it on the values I actually care about it appears to hit a race condition. It quickly reaches a point near the minimum, but bounces around it indefinitely until reaching the maximum number of calculations I allowed in the iterative settings. I have done some troubleshooting and found something weird. When the iterative calculation hits the max, if I copy the variable cell and paste it in place "by Value", the values of the objective cell change slightly. It appears that during the iterative calculation the intermediate and objective cells do not finish re-calculating before the next iteration is performed? Has anyone experienced this or know of a workaround?

A link to a sample sheet with the problem: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1clCfq-B3Iu-YAWwWTE0gz7SY8SKdDk0h1_wXVJm1t3U/edit?usp=sharing

Rows 1-4 contain the simple test that works (Change cell B1 to see it work). Cell B15 is the one that will be varied to try and get Cell B34 as close as possible to the input in B10. B35 is the absolute difference between B34 and B10, and is therefore the value to be minimized. Change the input in B10 to be somewhere from 5,000,000 to 9,000,000 to see the problem.

Edit: Adding pictures for posterity

[Simple test case that works properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Filez.png)

[Iterative Calculation Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7S26.png)

[After manually entering 28.4 into B15, notice the values in row 35 change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwcJf.png)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your code.  Links  are useless because if they are removed then the question is useless for other.

Comment: I feel "useless" is a bit of an exaggeration seeing as the link currently works, but I see your point. I will add info